# Clear several functions (with options)

Tags: ghidra

Is it possible to select and clear several functions without resorting to scripting from the Functions window (i.e right click->clear with options)? Currently I can only do it one-by-one on the Listing window:

[image: clear with options]

I would like to wipe clearly mis-identified/analyzed functions in one go, preferably from the Functions window directly?:

[image: ghidra functions]

And if I have to resort to scripting, does anybody have a snippet handy?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will have to resort to scripting for something like this, but it should be fairly easy. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use it? How do you decide which function to clear?

Comment: Fair point... I was just curious about how much I didn't know about the Ghidra UI (perhaps I missed some useful shortcuts?).

I guess I'll write up some small snippet for functions that are clearly misdetected (under a size threshold or with some clearly broken patterns).

Comment: Just found this question again and wanted to add that there is a dedicated reverse engineering stack exchange with a fairly active ghidra tag https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghidra
If you still have specific questions about some issues while writing the script this would be a good place to ask